# Commenting-out function body gives strange link error in VS 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, linker-errors

I'm trying to write simple binary tree program in C++ using VS 2012.Even all paths are set it give me link error  as shown in attached and when i comment the comment-out inside the insert function, it compiles without error.

[image]

```
// C++ code
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   cout <<" Simple Binary Tree Examples";

   getchar();

    return 0;
}

struct node
{
   int data;
   node *left;
   node *right;   
};

public class BinaryTree
{
   public :
      BinaryTree();
      ~BinaryTree();

      void insert(int value);
      /*{
         if(root==NULL)
         {
            insert(value,root);
         }
         else
         {
            root = new node;
            root->data=value;
         }
      }*/

      void delete_tree();

   private:
      node *root;
      void insert(int value,node *leaf);
};

BinaryTree::BinaryTree()
{
   root=NULL;
}

BinaryTree::~BinaryTree()
{
  delete_tree();
}

void BinaryTree::insert(int value)
{
   // If i un-comment the below code.. it gives link error.
  /* if(root==NULL)
   {
      insert(value,root);
   }
   else
   {
      root = new node;
      root->data=value;
   }*/
}
```

really dont know what could be wrong and hence shared the entire code.

Comment: try new node(); is this works?

Comment: @yossico - new node(); - did not work.

Comment: I don't see any function body defined for `delete_tree` although the class definition says it should exist.

Comment: ...it often helps, if you read the error message, then check anything mentioned there, such as `delete_tree` in this case. Just checking that would have led you to noticing that you can't find its definition anywhere, even if you didn't understand rest of the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't contain a definition of `delete_tree`, which is mentioned in your destructor.

It shouldn't compile neither with that code commented, nor with it.

Comment: got it.. after adding the defination for delete_tree and insert(value,root) function.. it compiles properly.. without error.